# Conditional probability question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If it does not rain, a flight arrives on time 80% of the time. If it does rain, the flight is on time 30% of the time. It rains 20% of the time. Find the probability that the flight arrives on time.

Question 1: To solve this I essentially found the expected value of arriving on time: (.2)*(.3)+(.8)(.8) = .7. Is this correct thinking?

Question 2: Say I wanted to find the probability that it rains and a flight arrives on time. Would this just be (.2)*(.3)?

Answer (score 2):

Your numbers look right, but it's hard to say if your *thinking* is correct as you haven't justified your answers. Here's a more systematic way of setting things up.

Let $R$ be "it rains". Let $A$ be "the plane arrives on time".

We have $P(A \mid R^{c}) = 0.8$ and $P(A \mid R) = 0.3$ and $P(R) = 0.2$.

Question 1: Use the law of total probability.

$P(A) = P(A \mid R)P(R) + P(A \mid R^{c})P(R^{c}) = (0.3)(0.2) + (0.8)(0.8)$.

Question 2: Use the definition of conditional probability.

$P(A \mid R)P(R) = P(A \cap R)$, which implies $P(A \cap R) = (0.3)(0.2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this: imagine 1000 different scenarios.  In .20(1000)= 200 of them it rains.  In the other 1000- 200= 800 it does not.

In the 200 scenarios in which it rains, the airplane is on time .3(200)= 60 times and not on time the other 200- 60= 140 times.

In the 800 scenarios in which it does not rain, the airplane is on time .8(800)= 640 times and is not on time the other 800- 640= 160 times.

So out of all 1000 scenarios, the airplane arrived on time 60+ 640= 700 times.  That is 700/1000= .7 or 70%.  That is the result you got.

```
Out or all 1000 scenarios, it rained and the airplane arrived on time 60 times.  That is 60/1000= .06 or 6%.  That is the same as your .2*.3= .06.
```